# Is codingstack.com somehow affiliated to stackexchange / stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stack Overflow clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones)

It looks like a complete attempted copy (UI and concept at least, not as much quality)... are they related? and why would anyone use codingstack.com over SO?

http://codingstack.com/

**Edit:**

Please close as duplicate, added this answer instead https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132041/141050

Comment: It appears to be open-source https://github.com/usmanasif/CodingStack (link in the footer of codingstack.com points to the github repo)

Comment: I like their [badge system](http://codingstack.com/badges). Imagine the sheer butthurt if getting downvoted just a couple times would prevent you from getting a gold badge on SO *forever*.

Comment: They have a [celebrity] badge, which has something to do with "followers". That's evidence enough right there that they have nothing to do with SE.

Comment: I like `{{count}} months ago`.

Comment: yes, saw it too and then thought about deleting my question here, feel free to downvote ;)

Comment: They also **only allow one line questions**. The bodies are identical to the "titles". That's utterly nuts.

Comment: @Felix it'll get fixed in `{{count}} - ({{count+2}})` weeks.

Comment: @Felix This must be what happens when you try to clone SO in a weekend.

Comment: @Pekka: Two weeks ago? :)

Comment: @Felix that `-` is a `to` :)

Comment: @Pekka: Ah :) That makes sense too :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unrelated.

It doesn't look *anything* "like a complete copy". It's a run-of-the-mill clone of Stack Overflow. They just be tryin to copy our swagga, and in the process, demonstrating that we really are doing something right.

It's an open source project, [available here on Github](https://github.com/usmanasif/CodingStack), if you're particularly compelled.

They also [have a blog](http://codingstack.blogspot.com/), but it's…not very active.

Comment: hmm They've been around since at least [9/10](http://codingstack.blogspot.com/2010_09_01_archive.html) they have 72 questions all time, [with 37 unanswered](http://codingstack.com/questions/unanswered). That fails as a Beta.SE site

Answer (score 2):

[image: An Image clearly showing the copyright notice of the site.]